# Symfony 2 - PHPUnit test and header already sent

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, authentication, phpunit

I have a problem with PHPUnit with Symfony2. I try to reproduce the login action. In my application I use web services to get data to log user, so I created a personal Userprovider. It works, if user data are good in the form, I create a cookie.There is two cookies created when I'm connecting : REMEMBER cookie (created automatically) and another cookie with some data.

I created a simple function to test my login page with this code :

```
// TEST page de login avec de bonnes informations
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();
$form['_username'] = $numero;
$form['_password'] = $pass;
$client->submit($form);
$client->followRedirects();
```

When I execute `phpunit -c app --coverage-html reports`
 There is no bug in the console but the file `test.log` said :

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning: "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\_dev\php\EasyPHP\data\localweb\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\Printer.php:139)" at C:\_dev\php\EasyPHP\data\localweb\myproject\src\project\projectBundle\Security\projectAuthenticator.php line 72 {"exception":"[object] (PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning(code: 2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by....
```

At the line 72 of file `projectAuthenticator.php` i created my cookie like this :

```
setcookie('mycookie', $cookieData, time() + (3600 * 24 * 365));
```

I tried to use [process isolation.](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runInSeparateProcess) but it's not working...

If I pass the creation of the cookie I return a `UsernamePasswordToken`object and i will be connected.

So how can I create my cookie to pass PHPUnit ? because I need the data of the cookie and a correct session to test private page and continue my tests...

I hope you understand

Thanks

Comment: Put `$client->followRedirects();` in the first place. Otherwise your code should be fine

Comment: You mean before `$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');` or at the start of the function test ?

Comment: After you create your client (after the line containing `static::createClient();`)

Comment: thanks, i got no error when i add arg `--stderr` like this : `phpunit -c app --coverage-html reports --stderr` . So i don't know if it's a solution...

Comment: I misunderstood you question, if you want to test your private pages you should have a look at this https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client and look for `PHP_AUTH_USER`.

Comment: And regarding the error, please make sure you don't have any `PHP header` left in your code

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Symfony classes when defining a cookie:

```
// Create the cookie
$nextYear = new \Datetime('now');
$nextYear->add(new \DateInterval('P1Y'));

$cookie = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie(
    'mycookie', $cookieData, $nextYear->format('U'));

$response = $this->render(
    'AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
    array(
        'variables' => $variables,
    )
);

// Add the cookie to the response
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);

return $response;
```

This will avoid the error reported by PHPUnit.